# XHR Post Response 200 but Failed to Execute Send

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am having an issue with a post to an Api.
The Api is using OAuth, I am generating all the valid information and posting it to the request_token url.
In Chrome Network tab I get a response 200 with the correct token in response,
but in the console I get an error and cannot get the response data.

```
NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://www.obsidianportal.com/oauth/request_token'.
```

If I set it to Async then it fails outright with a POST (cancelled)

```
xhr.open("POST", "https://www.obsidianportal.com/oauth/request_token", false);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
//xhr.responseType = "text/html";
//xhr.responseType = "text";
xhr.addEventListener("error", function() { console.log(xhr, arguments); }, false);
xhr.send(postData);
```

PostData is the generated OAuth information which is only valid once, so it is hard to debug.

Any help on this issue would be great.